# Android resume activity variables gone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Short:
I have Three classes: `A (MainActivity), B (Secondary), C(Third)`.
`A` is parent of `B` is parent of `C`.
In `A` I make an Intend with Extra `int idForUsage` on `B`. `B` stores `idForUsage` in a variable `int chosenId`(works fine).
`B` does Stuff and makes an Intent with Extra `int chosenId` and `int secondIdForUsage`(works also fine).
`C` does Stuff and it works all fine.

When I´m now clicking the litte "back button" in the upper left corner to get to the parent activity the app crashes because I´m trying to access the Variable `chosenId` which seems to being set to default -1 (even if I´m trying to read the Extra again.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //references to Buttons etc
    ...

    public static final String ChosenID = "com.example.Abzeichenschwimmer.ChosenSwimmerID";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //set up button stuff
        ...
        //ListView which has clickable Items which trigger the Activity
        lv_swimmerList = findViewById(R.id.lv_schwimmerListe);

        
        //Listeners
        
        lv_swimmerList.setOnItemClickListener(this::onListViewItemClick);
        }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updateSchwimmerliste(dataBaseHelper);
    }
    public void onListViewItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SchwimmerModel clickedSchwimmer = (SchwimmerModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplaySchwimmer.class);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(clickedSchwimmer.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra(ChosenSwimmerID, clickedSchwimmer.getId());
                startActivity(intent);

    }
    
}
```

```
public class DisplaySchwimmer extends AppCompatActivity {
    int chosenSwimmerID;
    
    public static final String SchwimmerID = "com.example.Abzeichenschwimmer.schwimmerID";
    public static final String AufgabenID = "com.example.Abzeichenschwimmer.aufgabenID";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_schwimmer);
        
        lv_exc = findViewById(R.id.lv_aufgaben);

        
        refreshValues();
        showAufgabenOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
        lv_exc.setOnItemClickListener(this::onListViewItemClick);
    }
    public void getIntentExtra(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        chosenSwimmerID = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.ChosenSwimmerID,-1);
    }
    public void onDeleteClick(View view){
        SchwimmerModel toDeleteSwimmer = (SchwimmerModel) dataBaseHelper.getSchwimmerByID(chosenSwimmerID);
        dataBaseHelper.deleteSchwimmer(toDeleteSwimmer);
        Toast.makeText(this, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DisplaySchwimmer.this.finish();
    }
    public void refreshValues(){
        getIntentExtra();
        SchwimmerModel schwimmer = dataBaseHelper.getSchwimmerByID(chosenSwimmerID); <--- Main Error
        
    }
    
    private void showAufgabenOnListView(DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper) {
        getIntentExtra();
        ArrayAdapter<ExcerciseModel> schwimmerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ExcerciseModel>(DisplaySchwimmer.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataBaseHelper.getExcersisesForSwimmerByID(chosenSwimmerID));
        lv_exc.setAdapter(schwimmerArrayAdapter);
    }

    public void onListViewItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ExcerciseModel clickedExcerciseModel = (ExcerciseModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(DisplaySchwimmer.this, DisplayAufgabe.class);
        intent2.putExtra(SchwimmerID, chosenSwimmerID);
        intent2.putExtra(AufgabenID, clickedExcerciseModel.getId());
        Log.e("aaa", String.valueOf(chosenSwimmerID));
        startActivity(intent2); <-- Intentstart
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        showAufgabenOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
    }

}
```

I hope the code (deleted many lines) is ok for an overview. Maybe someone knows the solution for this.
Thanks Maximus

Answer (score 0):

When you press back from `DisplayAufgabe` to `DisplaySchwimmer` (the intent always is null)

Because you call getIntent di DisplaySchwimmer, you will get default value which is -1 (null intent extra)

When you try to call `dataBaseHelper.getSchwimmerByID(chosenSwimmerID);` is mean you try to get index -1 on database. You will always get error because accessing index -1.

**My Suggestion**

Add validation before call dbHelper i.e

```
if (chosenSwimmerID > -1){
   SchwimmerModel schwimmer = dataBaseHelper.getSchwimmerByID(chosenSwimmerID);
}
```

Only getExtra when value available

```
if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.ChosenSwimmerID)){
   chosenSwimmerID = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.ChosenSwimmerID,-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all boiled down on using sharedPreferences. This helped a lot. A [Second post from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129797/android-finishing-intent-calls-oncreate-of-parent?noredirect=1#comment120414099_68129797) explanined this problem more simplified and I found a solution.