# Android finishing Intent calls onCreate() of parent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, oncreate

I´ve encountered the problem that my app keeps crashing because of a NullPointerException. A databaseQuery cant be made because of a missing value.
I´ve investigated, that the following ist happening:
class A is intended by MainActivity (with IntentExtra `int id`) .Class `A` makes Intent on `B`.
`B` finishes by clicking the "back" button (the hardware back button works actually. The Problem is with that one in the upper left corner).
`A.onCreate()` is called again (But the Intent creating this is not the same as before, thus not having the id Extra). But I´d like to return to the previous state of `A`. There are instances of variables I need to have.

Is there any workaround? Or why is onCreate beeing called?

Comment: onCreate() of A is being called since you started an activity (A) using Intent. If you want a variable to set to a specific value every time your program starts activity A, you can simply set that value in onCreate().

Comment: OK maybe my description wasn´t clear enough...
In MainActivity the user clicks on a Field in a Listview. This creates an Intent on A and gives it the Id clicked by the User. In A there is also a Listview of Elements. Here the User also clicks on one (id2). This intents B with the specific id,id2 to display further information. When B is closed by "back" it should "back up" at A with the Id given, so restoring the State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was:
Members of activitys get "wiped" when Stopped. To Prevent this you can use a SharedPreferences.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) is a good discription.
--> Saving persitent state